# Free hand drawing using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, drawing, html5-canvas, vml

What solutions other than HTML5 canvas can be used to implement free-hand drawing in JavaScript?

I have tried using HTML5 canvas but it did not work out as i was having problem in saving the canvas along with the text. Moreover the canvas can only be saved as image. But i need to save it in a format in which i can open and again draw and edit text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this question as it stands does not work here. You have to at least try something before you ask here.

Comment: I edited your answer. Please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) next time.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**
Now after you added more info to your question I know why you don't want to use canvas (which you still can use, but in a different way that you did before, but you may prefer another approach for you application - see below). People have voted to close your answer and it means that no new answer can be posted until it is reopened so I'll try update my answer. I have also voted to reopen your question.

### Drawing in JavaScript Options

For free-hand drawing in HTML you have only 3 options:

1. Canvas
2. SVG (VML on IE)
3. Plugins (eg. Flash, Java, Silverlight)

You didn't explain why you don't want to use canvas.

### Browser support

If the browser that you need to target doesn't support Canvas then you can:

- use SVG or VML (or a library that uses SVG/VML like Raphaël)
- use something that implements canvas (eg. in Flash) like:

  - http://code.google.com/p/fxcanvas/
  - http://flashcanvas.net/
  - http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

### API

If the native Canvas API doesn't suit your needs then you can use some canvas library that provides more functionality or a better API.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/
- http://processingjs.org/
- http://kineticjs.com/ (No longer maintained!)
- http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
- http://paperjs.org/
- http://www.bhivecanvas.com/
- http://fabricjs.com/

### Retained Mode vs. Immediate Mode

What you need is a [retained mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retained_mode) rendering (as opposed to [immediate mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode)).

Canvas is an example of an immediate mode rendering while SVG/VML work in retained mode. It means that once you draw something on canvas it's just pixels and you can't manipulate objects that were drawn or save anything other than a flat raster image. SVG on the other hand keeps the entire DOM of the objects that you draw (just like in HTML) and you can easily manipulate everything that you have there, attach events, change colors, fill styles, move things after they were drawn or saved etc.

You can still use Canvas to do what you want but you need some library to help you keep track of everything that is being drawn - a library that provides a retained mode as an abstraction layer on top of the immediate mode Canvas API - some of the libraries that I previously described work that way, see the links above - but still you may find another approach better suited for your needs.

### A Ready Solution

Take a look as the [SVG-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) (or on [GitHub](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit)) project - and especially see [the demo](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.7/editor/svg-editor.html) and other [projects that use SVG-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/wiki/ProjectsThatUseSvgEdit). Using SVG-edit would probably be the easiest way to achieve your goals.

Comment: I want to implement a NoteBook.I should be able to write and draw and save it in a format so that i can again open it and perform drawing and writing.When i used HTML5 canvas i was not able to save it in a format other than image.So i cant draw and write text on the image.